# How to group by row in diferents columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in SQL, I need to group it by the report name and I need to split the price_bucket column and the count_sales column in diferents rows.

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------+--+
| report_id | report_name | order_number | price_bucket_range | count_sales |  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------+--+
|        69 | London      |            1 | 0 - 1              |           4 |  |
|        69 | London      |            2 | 1 - 2              |           8 |  |
|        69 | London      |            3 | 2 - 3              |           2 |  |
|        69 | London      |            4 | 3 - 4              |           2 |  |
|        69 | London      |            5 | 4 - 1000           |           0 |  |
|        70 | Berlin      |            1 | 0 - 1              |          11 |  |
|        70 | Berlin      |            2 | 1 - 2              |           3 |  |
|        70 | Berlin      |            3 | 2 - 3              |           2 |  |
|        70 | Berlin      |            4 | 3 - 4              |           1 |  |
|        70 | Berlin      |            5 | 4 - 1000           |           1 |  |
|        71 | Paris       |            1 | 0 - 2              |           5 |  |
|        71 | Paris       |            2 | 2 - 3              |          17 |  |
|        71 | Paris       |            3 | 3 - 5              |           6 |  |
|        71 | Paris       |            4 | 5 - 10             |           0 |  |
|        71 | Paris       |            5 | 10 - 1000          |           1 |  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+-------------+--+
```

I think that I should use the PIVOT funtion in SQL Server and an intermediate table. How should I do it?

This is what the final table should look like:

```
| report_id | report_name | price_bucket_1 | count_sales_1 | price_bucket_2 | count_sales_2 | price_bucket_3 | count_sales_3 | price_bucket_4 | count_sales_4 | price_bucket_5 | count_sales_5 |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
|        69 | London      | 0 - 1          |             4 | 1 - 2          |             8 | 2 - 3          |             2 | 3 - 4          |             2 | 4 - 1000       |             0 |
|        70 | Berlin      | 0 - 1          |            11 | 1 - 2          |             3 | 2 - 3          |             2 | 3 - 4          |             1 | 4 - 1000       |             1 |
|        71 | Paris       | 0 - 2          |             5 | 2 - 3          |            17 | 3 - 5          |             6 | 5 - 10         |             0 | 10 - 1000      |             1 |
+-----------+-------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+
```

More info: The order_number column sometimes will have 5 rows and sometimes will have 4. In that case the last 2 columns must have 0. But never more than 5 rows.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Please take the time to provide your sample data (and expected results) as Tabular Formatted `text` or, even better, as DDL and DML statements. Images of really don't help us help you, as you're expecting us to have to transcribe your images to be able to use it. It also makes your question impossible to answer for those that have screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to list the buckets in order by the sales descending.  You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select report_id, report_name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price_bucket_range end) as bucket_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then count_sales end) as count_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price_bucket_range end) as bucket_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then count_sales end) as count_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then price_bucket_range end) as bucket_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then count_sales end) as count_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then price_bucket_range end) as bucket_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then count_sales end) as count_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then price_bucket_range end) as bucket_5,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then count_sales end) as count_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by report_id order by count_sales desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by report_id, report_name;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. It works perfectly for now. It was row_number() and conditional aggregation. I'm going to learn how to use them. They looks very useful.